# Make the diff understand indentation changes

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, edits, editor

If you change the indentation ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/25881090/revisions#spacer-8871be78-26a1-4202-bfc8-950021f30d52)) then the diff is really messed up:

[image: a mess]

Wouldn't it be possible to detect such changes, and e.g. try to remove the longest run of characters from the front?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have no idea when it happened, but it is fixed. Thanks!

Comment: It happened [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/247768/115866) :)